# start cassandra with "./bin/cassandra -f", how to have back the terminal window?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

when using `./bin/cassandra -f`, it shows:

```
Cz@z-EX465-MX:~/cassandra$ ./bin/cassandra -f
 INFO 09:12:19,460 Logging initialized
 INFO 09:12:19,484 Heap size: 1033895936/1033895936
 INFO 09:12:19,486 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 09:12:19,501 Loading settings from file:/home/z/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 09:12:19,711 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be standard, indexAccessMode is standard
 INFO 09:12:19,829 Creating new commitlog segment /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1297127539829.log
 INFO 09:12:19,888 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-12
 INFO 09:12:19,889 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-9
 INFO 09:12:19,890 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-11
 INFO 09:12:19,891 Deleted /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-10
 INFO 09:12:19,939 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-IndexInfo-KeyCache
 INFO 09:12:19,946 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-Schema-KeyCache
 INFO 09:12:19,949 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-Migrations-KeyCache
 INFO 09:12:19,952 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-LocationInfo-KeyCache
 INFO 09:12:19,962 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-13
 INFO 09:12:19,984 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-HintsColumnFamily-KeyCache
 INFO 09:12:20,043 Couldn't detect any schema definitions in local storage.
 INFO 09:12:20,045 Found table data in data directories. Consider using JMX to call org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.loadSchemaFromYaml().
 INFO 09:12:20,058 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1297127304757.log
 INFO 09:12:20,060 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1297127304757.log
 INFO 09:12:20,061 Log replay complete
 INFO 09:12:20,147 Cassandra version: 0.7.1-SNAPSHOT
 INFO 09:12:20,147 Thrift API version: 19.4.0
 INFO 09:12:20,168 Loading persisted ring state
 INFO 09:12:20,175 Starting up server gossip
 INFO 09:12:20,195 switching in a fresh Memtable for LocationInfo at CommitLogContext(file='/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1297127539829.log', position=89)
 INFO 09:12:20,197 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-LocationInfo@14850080(29 bytes, 1 operations)
 INFO 09:12:20,199 Writing Memtable-LocationInfo@14850080(29 bytes, 1 operations)
 INFO 09:12:20,604 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-14-Data.db (80 bytes)
 INFO 09:12:20,623 Starting Messaging Service on port 7000
 INFO 09:12:20,669 Using saved token 66456586001264063553489133185713650713
 INFO 09:12:20,670 switching in a fresh Memtable for LocationInfo at CommitLogContext(file='/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-1297127539829.log', position=270)
 INFO 09:12:20,671 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-LocationInfo@5006112(53 bytes, 2 operations)
 INFO 09:12:20,671 Writing Memtable-LocationInfo@5006112(53 bytes, 2 operations)
 INFO 09:12:20,938 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/LocationInfo-f-15-Data.db (163 bytes)
 INFO 09:12:20,945 Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath
 INFO 09:12:21,008 Binding thrift service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9160
 INFO 09:12:21,013 Using TFastFramedTransport with a max frame size of 15728640 bytes.
 INFO 09:12:21,016 Listening for thrift clients...
```

so when browse `127.0.0.1:9160`, it shows blank white page. but I cannot use this terminal window except pressing `Ctrl+c` and stop cassandra.

I'm looking if I can use `./bin/cassandra -f &` to have back the terminal window, but when trying `pgrep thrift` or `pgrep cassandra`, I found nothing. I dont know how to stop it when using other terminal window

Answer (score 11):

The -f is for foreground.  Just omit it, if you want Cassandra to daemonize.

Answer (score 3):

solved.
use `pgrep java` to see the process

Answer (score 2):

On a *nix system, you should be able to type ctrl-z to halt the foreground cassandra process. That will give you a prompt, if you then type bg at the prompt, the cassandra process will be backgrounded.  You can do this with any foreground process that you need to background.

Answer (score 1):

if you do use a combination of *-f* and *&* then your job is in the background.

you can just enter:

```
fg
```

to bring it back to the foreground and then CTRL-C

or use:

```
jobs
```

to see what you have in the background. then you can use fg with the job number.

You can also use CTRL-Z to suspend whatever is currently running on the terminal, then use:

```
bg
```

to background it.

Here is an example session where I run *tail* twice and demonstrate putting it on and off the terminal

```
rob@deathstar:~$ tail -f /var/log/messages &
[1] 13074                                            <-- that's the PID :) 
rob@deathstar:~$ tail -f /var/log/daemon.log &
[2] 13089
rob@deathstar:~$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 tail -f /var/log/messages &
[2]+  Running                 tail -f /var/log/daemon.log &
rob@deathstar:~$ fg 1
tail -f /var/log/messages
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 tail -f /var/log/messages
rob@deathstar:~$ bg
[1]+ tail -f /var/log/messages &
rob@deathstar:~$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 tail -f /var/log/messages &
[2]+  Running                 tail -f /var/log/daemon.log &
rob@deathstar:~$ fg 2
tail -f /var/log/daemon.log
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 tail -f /var/log/daemon.log
rob@deathstar:~$ bg
[2]+ tail -f /var/log/daemon.log &
rob@deathstar:~$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 tail -f /var/log/messages &
[2]+  Running                 tail -f /var/log/daemon.log &
rob@deathstar:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

./cassandra -f pid.txt

Your process will run in background automatically and push the process id into a file. Will be helpful to stop cassandra process using the process id in pid.txt.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Windows.... you would need to restart the cluster again as once the service is running in the foreground, the cluster will need to be restarted