# Problems starting Cassandra with “./bin/cassandra -f”

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, thrift, ubuntu-server

For some reason when I try to start Cassandra with this command:

```
bin/cassandra -f
```

The terminal gets stuck on:

Listening for thrift clients...

Is it normal? Does that mean that Thrift can talk too Thrift?

I am using Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That sounds normal. Cassandra -f doesn't create an interactive session, it just runs Cassandra in the foreground, but as a server process.

To interact with Cassandra, you can start a CLI session in another terminal window. See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli for details of how to do this, and the commands that you can run.

There are also clients for various programming languages - see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions

See also [start cassandra with "./bin/cassandra -f", how to have back the terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928669/start-cassandra-with-bin-cassandra-f-how-to-have-back-the-terminal-window)

Comment: Or just omit the -f in the first place. There's no point telling Cassandra to run in the foreground (-f) and then immediately put it in the background (&)

Comment: I like -f option because it keeps telling me what's going on at server terminal and shows me errors if any.

Comment: How can I restart Cassandra in my system, when I have started it through 
`~/<CASSANDRA_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/bin$ sudo sh cassandra`
As because whenever I make changes in cassandra.yaml file, say for ex. changing the `native_transport_port`, those changes aren't reflected when I run my application, and for an available solution, I have to perform a reboot of my system so as to reflect those changes ! How can I restart Cassandra from Terminal in this case ?

Comment: If you are running cassandra directly (not as a service) then you need to kill the process, and then start it again. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433802/how-do-i-restart-apache-cassandra-2-0-4 or https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/reference/referenceStartStopTOC.html