# How do i restart apache cassandra 2.0.4?

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I have one node Cassandra 2.0.4 up and running i need to restart it after configuration change i tired restarting it by referring [this](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandra) but not working

```
>cassandra/bin/cassandra -p new
 Error: Exception thrown by the agent :java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 >kill $(cat new)
-bash: kill: (10404) - No such process
```

I did installation referring [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-a-ubuntu-vps)

Till now when I have to restart it, I am doing by restarting server on which Cassandra is running.

Please tell me what is the proper way to restart apache Cassandra 2.0.4

Comment: I have last option to restart the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's only a process and not a service you could do something like

```
$ ps auwx | grep cassandra
$ sudo kill <pid>
```

where `<pid>` is what you get from `ps auwx | grep cassandra`

This will stop the process. Then you have to start it again

```
$ cd <install_location>
$ bin/cassandra
```

where `<install_location>` is where you have installed cassandra

if is a service: `service cassandra restart`

Comment: it is not working with me it will workout with Datastax installation i have apache cassandra i tried that from this link http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/start_stop_ref

Comment: Any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use these commands:

```
$ service dse start/stop/restart
```